# Увеличить объем оперативной памяти приложения

Tags: qt, c++

Во время работы приложение занимает всю оперативную память (более 1000 мб). Я так понимаю это просто ограничение. Как убрать это ограничение. Чтобы приложение могло занимать, например, все 8 гб. ОП

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перейдите на 64-битную платформу. Иначе вам придётся [вручную переключать страницы памяти](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040810-00/?p=38203) (это не самое приятное занятие, и чревато дичайшими проблемами).

И вас ограничивает не объём оперативки (физическая память), а размер выделенного процессу адресного пространства (виртуальная память). Не забывайте, в этой физической памяти бежит ещё пол-тысячи процессов.